# Bootstrap - scrollspy responsivness not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem with responsivness of the page. If I go to half width of the page, the scrollspy disapear. I have no idea why.

You can see whole page if you run code I posted here.

I have another page that has not problem with responsivnes, there I do not use scrollspy.

I would like to give you more information, but I've used Bootstrap 3x and now I am doing just a school project.

[here it is displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvRoi.jpg)

[here not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfeuL.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CONFT</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo_tab_icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
      body 
      {
          background-color: white; 
      }

      .navbar 
      {
          background-color: black;
      }

      .nav-pills .active
      {
      /*  FARBA AKTÍVNEHO TABU V NAVIGÁCII A JEHO ZAOBLENIE */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%);
      border-radius: 2%;
      }

      .row.first-row {
          margin-top: 1em;
          margin-right: 4em;
          margin-left: 4em;
      }
      h4.white 
      {
          color: white;
      }

      #tl
      /* TLAČIDLÁ "What I will learn?" */
      {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      margin-top: 0.5em;
      }

      /* info SÚ INFORMÁCIE O AUTOROVI V BIELOM PÁSE */
      .info 
      {
      margin-top: 3em;
      padding-top: 2em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      }

      .info p 
      {
      padding-top: 0.2em;
      }

      footer 
      {
      margin-top: 50px;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
      {
          div.col-md-4
          {
              margin-bottom: 1em;
          }
      }
      /* CSS FOR SCROLLSPY */
      body                                
      {
        position: relative;
      }

      ul.nav-pills.flex-column 
      {
        top: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }

      div.col-8 div 
      {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
      }

      .row
      {
        width: 500px;
      }

      div.content-author
      {
        width: 800px;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () 
        {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="1">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:50px;">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About author</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="CCNA 3" 
                    data-content="This course is already in progress. Stay tuned.">CCNA 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="d-none d-xl-block col-xl-2 bd-toc disapear1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>

              <div class="col-sm-7 col-8 content-author disapear2">
                <div id="section1" class="bg-success">    
                  <h1>Section 1</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="bg-warning"> 
                  <h1>Section 2</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>        
                <div id="section3" class="bg-secondary">         
                  <h1>Section 3</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section41" class="bg-danger">         
                  <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>      
                <div id="section42" class="bg-info">         
                  <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="bg-primary text-white text-center text-lg-start">
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="text-center p-3" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%">
            © 2021 Copyright: René Martin Kuda, SPŠT Spišská Nová Ves, 3.D
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
      </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see the whole page because at some point (on the div you want to see) you have `.d-none .d-xl-block` , this will let visible the div with these classes only on xl screen devices

So you should remove these and it would become:

```
<div class="col-xl-2 bd-toc disapear1">
```

Will share the full code just with that little correction, you also forgot to close the inline-style on the div in the footer (fixed as well) here you are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CONFT</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo_tab_icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
      body 
      {
          background-color: white; 
      }

      .navbar 
      {
          background-color: black;
      }

      .nav-pills .active
      {
      /*  FARBA AKTÍVNEHO TABU V NAVIGÁCII A JEHO ZAOBLENIE */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%);
      border-radius: 2%;
      }

      .row.first-row {
          margin-top: 1em;
          margin-right: 4em;
          margin-left: 4em;
      }
      h4.white 
      {
          color: white;
      }

      #tl
      /* TLAČIDLÁ "What I will learn?" */
      {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      margin-top: 0.5em;
      }

      /* info SÚ INFORMÁCIE O AUTOROVI V BIELOM PÁSE */
      .info 
      {
      margin-top: 3em;
      padding-top: 2em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      }

      .info p 
      {
      padding-top: 0.2em;
      }

      footer 
      {
      margin-top: 50px;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
      {
          div.col-md-4
          {
              margin-bottom: 1em;
          }
      }
      /* CSS FOR SCROLLSPY */
      body                                
      {
        position: relative;
      }

      ul.nav-pills.flex-column 
      {
        top: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }

      div.col-8 div 
      {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
      }

      .row
      {
        width: 500px;
      }

      div.content-author
      {
        width: 800px;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () 
        {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="1">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:50px;">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About author</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="CCNA 3" 
                    data-content="This course is already in progress. Stay tuned.">CCNA 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="col-xl-2 bd-toc disapear1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>

              <div class="col-sm-7 col-8 content-author disapear2">
                <div id="section1" class="bg-success">    
                  <h1>Section 1</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="bg-warning"> 
                  <h1>Section 2</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>        
                <div id="section3" class="bg-secondary">         
                  <h1>Section 3</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section41" class="bg-danger">         
                  <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>      
                <div id="section42" class="bg-info">         
                  <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="bg-primary text-white text-center text-lg-start">
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="text-center p-3" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%)">
            © 2021 Copyright: René Martin Kuda, SPŠT Spišská Nová Ves, 3.D
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
      </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

p.s. i saw that now the first section is hidden by the navbar, you should set a margin-top to avoid that

Comment: thx it helps! but now I'm facing problem with that margin-top in css - if I adjust margin-top of .row or even .content-author, the scrollspy nav is not working properly - the Section 1 is not active from beginning of page refresh -> I have to scroll a down (to the position like you mention that is hidden) and after this the Section 1 in navbar is active.

Comment: ok, I get it - I had to use an data-offset (i set it to 80)

Answer (score 1):

Simple Remove `d-none`  class for -->> div class="d-none d-xl-block col-xl-2 bd-toc disapear1"> use

```
div class="d-xl-block col-xl-2 bd-toc disapear1">
```